# Storing Bash function parameters in variables

Tags: bash, function, variables, parameter-passing

I want to define and get all the required variables that are passed to a function as parameters:

```
function explain_vars() {
  echo "Explaining vars '$@':" >&2
  for _var in "$@"; do
    printf "  $_var: '${!_var}'\n" >&2
  done
  printf "\n" >&2
}

function read_params() (
  ## Define local variables
  _vars=(v1 v2 v3) 
  local ${_vars[@]}

  ## Read variables from input:
  read ${_vars[@]} <<< "$@"
  explain_vars "${_vars[@]}"
)
```

The read takes puts all parameters in the specified variables, default delimiter here is space. So if I pass different strings as second parameter, `read` will store only the first string in the second parameter, and all the rest to the following parameters:

```
$ read_params one "two dot one" "three" "four"
Explaining vars 'v1 v2 v3':
  v1: 'one'
  v2: 'two'
  v3: 'dot one three four'
```

As we can see, variable v2 is not synchronized with given parameters anymore. Moreover, it fails at reading empty strings:

```
$ read_params one "" " " '' ' ' "two dot one" "three" "four"
Explaining vars 'v1 v2 v3':
  v1: 'one'
  v2: 'two'
  v3: 'dot one three four'
```

By looping through the all-parameters variable $@ inside the function it is possible to distinguish variables:

```
function raw_params() (
  echo "Explaining row parameters:"
  for _v in "${@}"; do
    printf "  '$_v'\n"
  done
)

$ raw_params one "" " " '' ' ' "two dot one" "three" "four"
Explaining row parameters:
  'one'
  ''
  ' '
  ''
  ' '
  'two dot one'
  'three'
  'four'
```

To me the `read` command offers benefit and quickness at defining, controlling and checking requested parameters that are passed to functions. However this works only for single and non-empty stringed parameters. Is it possible to read all different parameters in variables like the `read` command does, but respecting spaces and empty parameters? Or is there a better approach maybe?

Comment: When you check `man bash`, _Here Strings_ it says: "`<<<word`: The `word` undergoes brace  expansion,  tilde  expansion,  parameter  and variable  expansion,  command  substitution,  arithmetic expansion, and **quote removal**." (emphasis me). In other words you lose the quotes and with that parameter "grouping" you've expected and needed.

Comment: So `read` cannot be used in my case? Reading from `stdin` will also remove quotes.

Answer (score 2):

From the original question seems `read` command is not correctly understood, `read` is a builtin which reads one line for standard input, `IFS` environment variable is used as field separator and `-d` option allows to change record delimiter (default is newline), for more information see `read` in bash manual.

The function arguments are retrieved using special variable `"$@"`, bash syntax to assign an array is just

```
_vars=( "$@" )   # no space between variable name and = and no space between = and (
```

As a space is not valid in a variable name `${!_var}` expansion will fail writing an error `bash: ...: bad substitution`, if _var contains an expression with a space.

`function` keyword is useless because of `()`, the use of parenthesis around the body of function instead of braces `{ ;}` starts a new sub-shell.

Comment: Ah I got it for the array assignment. However in my loop case I cannot directly declare and update the array without using `eval` statement. (` printf -v "${_vars[p-1]}" "${!p}"`). Should I avoid the use of parenthesis for my subshell functions in my case?

Comment: @kaligne, i'm not sure to understand your need, i can't answer if subshell is needed but i don't think so why do you think it's needed? what is your intention with _vars?

Comment: I was just wondering if your take on that was just informative or an advise to use / not use the parenthesis. Here I used them to not declare _var as local, I thought it would (relatively) save time . But the thing here is the variables that _var contains have to be declared local anyway. So in the end I didn't use the parenthesis for any particular need

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are hoping to accomplish with this code, but this would appear to solve your problem for the case of three input parameters. Perhaps it shows you a way forward even if it doesn't completely do what you want.

```
read_params () (
  ## Define local variables
  _vars=(v1 v2 v3) 
  local ${_vars[@]}

  local i
  for ((i=1; i<=$#; ++i)); do
     ## Read variables from input:
     printf -v "${_vars[i-1]}" "${!i}"
  done
  explain_vars "${_vars[@]}"
)
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to be a nice lead. `printf -v` correctly assigns parameters to variables. However it fails at assigning empty parameters in arrays. I found a workaround as explained in my answer below.

Comment: (There is no "above" or "below"; these posts are shown in different order depending on votes, age, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote my function in a script according to `tripleee`'s answer. `printf` works fine except for assigning empty values ('' and "") to `arrays`. For that, we need to format the string we pass to `printf -v` with '%s'. For the example I pass an array of parameters to my function twice: once per assigning them to my regular local parameters; a second time to pass the same parameters to my last local array variable. Here is the code:

```
$ cat parse-local-vars.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function explain_vars() {
  echo "Explaining vars '$@':" >&2
  for _var in "$@"; do
    printf "  $_var: '${!_var}'\n" >&2
  done
}

function parse_params() (
  #
  # Stores given parameters in defined local variables _vars.
  # Last variable will be treated as an array and 
  # remaining parameters will be stored therein.
  #

  ## Define local variables
  local _vars=(v1 v_empty_double_quote v_spaced_double_quote v_empty_single_quote v_spaced_single_quote v2_1 v3 v4 args) 
  local ${_vars[@]}

  ## Make sure we assign parameters to variables
  [ ${#_vars[@]} -gt 0 ] \
    || return 1

  _args_pos=$(( ${#_vars[@]}-1 ))
  _args_counter=0
  local p
  for ((p=1; p<=$#; ++p)); do
     ## Read variables from input:
     if [ $p -le $_args_pos ]; then
       #printf -v "${_vars[p-1]}" '%s' "${!p}"
       printf -v "${_vars[p-1]}" "${!p}"  
     else
       #printf -v "${_vars[_args_pos]}[$_args_counter]" '%s' "${!p}"
       printf -v "${_vars[_args_pos]}[$_args_counter]" "${!p}"  # Without the '%s' assigning empty variable to an array does not work
       _args_counter=$(( _args_counter+1 ))
     fi
  done
  explain_vars "${_vars[@]}"
  echo "exlaining array args[@]: '${args[@]}'"
  for _v in "${args[@]}"; do
    echo "   >'$_v'"
  done
)

params_to_test=(one "" "  " '' '  ' "two dot one" "three" "four")
parse_params "${params_to_test[@]}" "${params_to_test[@]}"
```

As one can see, here I use `printf -v` without formatting the parameter string (no use of `'%s'`):

```
$ bash parse-local-vars.sh
Explaining vars 'v1 v_empty_double_quote v_spaced_double_quote v_empty_single_quote v_spaced_single_quote v2_1 v3 v4 args':
  v1: 'one'
  v_empty_double_quote: ''
  v_spaced_double_quote: '  '
  v_empty_single_quote: ''
  v_spaced_single_quote: '  '
  v2_1: 'two dot one'
  v3: 'three'
  v4: 'four'
  args: 'one'
exlaining array args[@]: 'one       two dot one three four' (6 values)
   >'one'
   >'  '
   >'  '
   >'two dot one'
   >'three'
   >'four'
```

The empty parameters "" and '' are not passed to the array (6 values).
Allowing the string formatting of `printf` by toggling the following comments:

```
printf -v "${_vars[_args_pos]}[$_args_counter]" '%s' "${!p}"
#printf -v "${_vars[_args_pos]}[$_args_counter]" "${!p}"  # Without the '%s' as,signing empty variable to an array does not work
```

Leads to this output:

```
$ bash parse-local-vars.sh
Explaining vars 'v1 v_empty_double_quote v_spaced_double_quote v_empty_single_quote v_spaced_single_quote v2_1 v3 v4 args':
  v1: 'one'
  v_empty_double_quote: ''
  v_spaced_double_quote: '  '
  v_empty_single_quote: ''
  v_spaced_single_quote: '  '
  v2_1: 'two dot one'
  v3: 'three'
  v4: 'four'
  args: 'one'
exlaining array args[@]: 'one         two dot one three four' (8 values)
   >'one'
   >''
   >'  '
   >''
   >'  '
   >'two dot one'
   >'three'
   >'four'
```

This is the expected results, as empty strings are correctly assigned to the array (8 values). I haven't figured out what is going on with passing empty strings to an array with `printf -v`, but using formatted strings with `printf -v` seems to be the safe way to go. Any correction, explanation and improvements are welcome.